# Integration of Django-PayPal subscription based payment system

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to implement a Subscription-based payment method in Django. I have tried to Integrate the subscription-based button as per the PayPal guidlines. Screenshot is attached for same.

[image: Subscription-based button]

But after clicking on either button screen is blank, and nothing happens, screenshot is attached for the same.

[image]

Here is my code for button integration.

```
<div id="paypal-button-container-P-789654"></div>
```

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=123456&vault=true&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'pill',
          color: 'blue',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'subscribe'
      },
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
          /* Creates the subscription */
          plan_id: 'P-789654'
        });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        alert(data.subscriptionID); // You can add optional success message for the subscriber here
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container-P-789654'); // Renders the PayPal button
</script>
```

Comment: Test with a different, non-Brave browser

Comment: We have already tried all browsers !

Comment: Use one without extensions, and do not host on 127.0.0.1 or localhost nor a non-standard port like :8000